# AngularJS handle calling promise multiple times with some exceptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I asked this question before ([AngularJS handle calling promise multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303136/angularjs-handle-calling-promise-multiple-times)) and now I have different obstacle. Now I have to get cities list but there is an exception.

Cities can be called multiple times like countries (in my old question) and I have to cache data to prevent multiple calls for same data(cities). Old question's solution can block multiple calls but now I have to let some calls (for new country's cities).

So my question is:
How can I cache cities data to prevent call for same data? 
(My function have to catch if call is for new country's cities list or not. if yes: call service and get cities, if not: return cities from cache)

Here is my service:

```
var cityCache = {};
vm.getCities = function (countryCode) {

    if (countryCode!=undefined && !cityCache[countryCode]) {

        vm.cityPromise = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            cache: true,
            url: API + '/api/Global/CountryCities',
            data: {
                "CountryCode": countryCode
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response,countryCode) {
            if (errorHandler(response.data)) {
                console.log("cities come from ajax")
                cityCache[response.config.data.CountryCode] = response.data;
                console.log(cityCache)
                return response.data
            }
        });
    } else {
        vm.cityPromise = $timeout(function () {//I use this to get promise object
            return cityCache[countryCode]
        }, 0)
        console.log("cities comes from cache");
    }

    return vm.cityPromise;
}
```

Example:
Let's say I am calling getCities function 3 times in the same time. I am watching my network traffic via chrome. I see 3 ajax calls. It's normal. But sometimes, I call for same city. I need to edit my function that can understand if city data is already called before (kind of cache). 
For example: If i ask function 3 times with this arguments: 
1-Give me the cities in Germany,
2-Give me the cities in Ireland,
3-Give me the cities in Germany (again), 
It's calling 3 times. But I want 1 call for Germany, 1 call for Ireland. Just 2 calls.

Comment: Question is unclear. What exactly is it you want to do? And what exactly is it that doesnt work in your code?

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as your other question, just map to country code to the promise.
Also same as before, consider the error case.

```
var vm = this;

vm.cityPromises = {};

function getCities(countryCode) {
    if (!vm.cityPromises[countryCode]) {
        vm.cityPromises[countryCode] = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            cache: true,
            url: API + '/api/Global/Countries',
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (errorHandler(response.data)) {
                console.log("ajax")
                return response.data;
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("cache")
    }
    return vm.cityPromises[countryCode];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wrote my function like yours before you answered and it worked! :) I wrote my solution as an aswer here. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own promise here. Don't forget injecting the $q service.

```
var cityCache = {};

vm.getCities = function (countryCode) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (countryCode!=undefined && !cityCache[countryCode]) {
        vm.cityPromise = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            cache: true,
            url: API + '/api/Global/CountryCities',
            data: {
                "CountryCode": countryCode
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response,countryCode) {
            if (errorHandler(response.data)) {
                cityCache[response.config.data.CountryCode] = response.data;
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            }
            else{
                deferred.reject();
            }
        });
    } 
    else {
         vm.cityPromise = $timeout(function () {//I use this to get promise object
             deferred.resolve(cityCache[countryCode]);
        }, 0);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Please check my old question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303136/angularjs-handle-calling-promise-multiple-times  I am having the same problem with your example too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [$q](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6757/) service from angular:

updated to prevent multiple call of same city:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6757/)

the service:

```
.service("cityService", function($http, $q, $httpParamSerializerJQLike){
    //var callCache = {};
    var cityCache = {};
    return {
        getCities: function(countryCode){

            //if(callCache[countryCode] === undefined){
                  var promise = $q.defer();
           //     callCache[countryCode] = promise;
            //}else{
            //      console.log("return cached promise!!", callCache[countryCode]);
            //      return callCache[countryCode].promise;
            //}

            if (countryCode!=undefined && !cityCache[countryCode]) {
                    console.log("new city");
                var data = $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
                    json: JSON.stringify({
                        name: countryCode+Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
                    })
                });
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url:"/echo/json/",
                    data: data
                }).then(function(risp) {
                        console.log("servicelog",risp.data);
                        cityCache[countryCode] = risp.data;
                    var obj = angular.extend({cache: false}, risp.data);
                    promise.resolve(obj);
                    //callCache[countryCode].resolve(obj);
                    //delete callCache[countryCode];
                });
            }else{
                setTimeout(function(){
                        var obj = angular.extend({cache: true}, cityCache[countryCode]);
                    promise.resolve(obj);
                    //callCache[countryCode].resolve(obj)
                    //delete callCache[countryCode];
                }, 1000)
            }
            return promise.promise;
        }
    }  
});
```

Comment: Please check my old question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303136/angularjs-handle-calling-promise-multiple-times. I am having the same problem with your example too.

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: Let's say I am calling getCities function 15 times in the same time. I am watching my network traffic via chrome. I see 15 ajax calls. It's normal. But sometimes, I call for same city. I need to edit my function that can understand if city data is already called before (kind of cache). 

For example: If i ask function 3 times with this arguments:
Give me the cities in Germany + Give me the cities in Ireland +Give me the cities in Germany (again), It's calling 3 times. But I want 1 call for Germany, 1 call for Ireland. Just 2 calls.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating an object for the promise and many thanks to @Luke Harper for helping me before and now :) His answer is also correct but I must add a bit more code for my app.

If you see any problem in my code, please write to me so that I would edit the answer

So here is my solution:

```
vm.cityPromise = {};
vm.getCities = function (countryCode) {
    vm.cityPromise["cityCache"] = countryCode;
    if (!vm.cityPromise[countryCode]) {
        if (countryCode != undefined && !cityCache[countryCode]) {
            vm.cityPromise[countryCode] = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                cache: true,
                url: API + '/api/Global/CountryCities',
                data: {
                    "CountryCode": countryCode
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response, countryCode) {
                if (errorHandler(response.data)) {
                    cityCache[response.config.data.CountryCode] = response.data;
                    console.log("cities ajax, cityCache", cityCache)
                    return response.data
                }
            },function error (response){
                console.log ("error:",response)
            });
        } else {
            vm.cityPromise[countryCode] = $timeout(function () {
                return cityCache[countryCode]
            }, 0)
            console.log("getCities cache");
        }
    }
    return vm.cityPromise[countryCode];
}
```